# Progressbar in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, progress-bar

Need Progressbar for indicate the battery level in my app by using phonegap. But while googling progressbar in phonegap, it shows the loading indicator and so on. Nothing find useful for my project. Anybody know help me. Need like this.[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jquery UI Progress bar to do this.

Follow this link [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/).

Hope this is what you were searching for.

Sample usage is like this

jQuery Code

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 37
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```